# c++ template parameter is ambiguous

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, type-mismatch

I am trying to implement three functions and have a lot of errors all of which have the same signature:

```
error C2782: 'T0 ColorBurn(T0,T0)' : template parameter 'T0' is ambiguous
error C2782: 'T1 ColorDodge(T1,T1)' : template parameter 'T1' is ambiguous
```

Where I have make a mistake?
This is my code:

```
template <class T0>
T0 ColorBurn(T0 base, T0 blend)
{
    return (blend == 0.0) ? blend : std::max((1.0 - ((1.0 - base) / blend)), 0.0);
}
template <class T1>
T1 ColorDodge(T1 base, T1 blend)
{
    return (blend == 1.0) ? blend : std::min(base / (1.0 - blend), 1.0);
}
template <class T>
T BlendVividLightf(T base, T blend)
{
    return (blend < 0.5) ? ColorBurn(base, (2.0 * blend)) : ColorDodge(base, (2.0 * (blend - 0.5)));
}
```

the sample of calling BlendVividLightf:

```
static pixel_t blend_vivid_light(pixel_t _p1, pixel_t _p2)
{
    pixel_t po;
    po.r = BlendVividLightf(_p1.r, _p2.r);
....
}
 pixel_t - is my struct for rgb values:
typedef struct  
{
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
} pixel_t;
```

Comment: What type is T in BlendVividLightf. Show the call of this function please.

Comment: Are `_p1.r` and `_p2.r` of type `double` ? If no then it will cause compilation errors.

Comment: _p1.r and _p2.r are float. why it could cause problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can guess, that the problem is due to mismatch of `float` and `double`. You are making (forcing) both `template` arguments of same type `T0/T1/T` in all the 3 functions. So when you call the function using `float` it will have problem. See the [demo](http://ideone.com/YT3MA) here.

This can be solved by making your `pixel_t` members as `double` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that when you call `ColorBurn` and `ColorDodge`, one of the template arguments is a float and the other is a double:

```
ColorBurn(base, (2.0 * blend))
```

Here, `base` is a float, and the expression `2.0 * blend` is a double (because `2.0` is a double constant, so the whole expression becomes double).

Now, the compiler can't decide whether to instantiate `ColorBurn` for float or for double.

To fix this, change your constants to single-precision float constants (which is likely what you want anyway):

```
ColorBurn(base, (2.0f * blend))
```

And similarly for `ColorDodge`.

Note that you'll still have trouble if you try to instantiate `BlendVividLightf` for something other than float -- your functions assume in too many ways that you're dealing with floating-point values, so you'll have to introduce some type conversions if you want them to work for other argument types.

Comment: The solution is to use `static_cast<T>(2.0)`. Or to use named constants: `static T const doubler = 2.0;`.  Either way, you force the constant to have the desired type.

Comment: @James: Or, just as a minor tweak, `static_cast<T>(2)` (to emphasize that this will only work with integral constants)

Comment: If I understand his code correctly, it will only work with floating point types.

Comment: @James: In its present state, yes -- but I was assuming he might eventually want to make it work on integral types as well...

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the problem is that `0.5` is a `double`-literal, and `T0` is a float. So you are passing the template two parameters with different types, and thus the compiler cannot decide which one to use. There are two solution:

1. Change `0.5` to `0.5f` to make it a `float`-literal.
2. Provide explicit type-parameters to your templates, like so:

   ```
   ColorBurn<float>(base, (2.0 * blend))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have to cast the result of  (2.0 * blend) to "T" and pass it to ColorBurn...
For instance:

```
ColorBurn(base, static_cast<T>(2.0 * blend));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
ColorBurn(base, (2.0 * blend)) ...
```

Here literal 2.0 will force conversion of second parameter to `double` , however since first parameter is its original template type, and in your code later on it's `float`, the compiler is unable to deduce whether you meant to call `ColorBurn<double>` or `ColorBurn<float>` (same applies to call to `ColorDodge` later in this line).

You can fix the error by either of:

- telling the compiler explicitly template parameter in the function call
- forcing conversion to double of the first parameter too e.g. `... * 1.0`
- changing double literals in the second parameter to float literals e.g. `... * 2.0f`
- writing specialisation, or separate overloads, for float and double and making appropriate changes above to ensure both parameters are same type